# How to Disconnect and do not reconnect until page refresh complete using Socket.io, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on a task where I am using Node.js with socket.io, express and mysql-events node.js module to emit data whenever new record inserted into the table.

I have done with all the stuff connection to emit and display, but I am facing the page refresh issue. When I tried to click on another link or I'll refresh the page, it is taking lot of time to get link open or refresh if node.js server running and continuously emitting data. but when node.js not running then there is no issue.

I have tried to disconnect the on page reload event, but this also not help me.

**Update**

```
// server.js that running on server side.

var app = require('express')();
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http, {
  'transports': [
      'websocket'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
  ],
  'close timeout': 60,
  'heartbeat timeout': 60,
  });

var mysql = require('mysql');
var MySQLEvents = require('mysql-events');
var request = require('request');


var dsn = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tester'
};

var mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 25,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'tester',
    database: 'test'
});
var myCon = MySQLEvents(dsn, {
  startAtEnd: false, // it overrides default value "true"
  includeEvents: ['writerows'],
  includeSchema: {'test': ['ttest']},
});

var barCols = [], barRows = [];
var pieCols = [], pieRows = [];
var jsonBarChart, jsonPieChart;

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){


//  console.log("====================== Connected ======================" +socket.id);
     var event1 = myCon.add(
      'test.ttest',
      function (oldRow, newRow) {
        if(newRow !== null){
            var data = {
                dd: newRow.fields,
            };
            io.emit('my-channel', data);

//      try {
//          global.gc();
//        } catch (e) {
//          console.log("You must run program with 'node --expose-gc index.js' or 'npm start'");
//          process.exit();
//        }
        }
      }
    );
     myCon.stop();
});
```

// index.html client side.

```
var socket = null;
    $(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
        socket.disconnect();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var connectionOptions =  {
                "force new connection" : true,
                "reconnection": true,
                "reconnectionDelay": 2000,                  //starts with 2 secs delay, then 4, 6, 8, until 60 where it stays forever until it reconnects
                "reconnectionDelayMax" : 60000,             //1 minute maximum delay between connections
                "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",         //to prevent dead clients, having the user to having to manually reconnect after a server restart.
                "timeout" : 10000,                           //before connect_error and connect_timeout are emitted.
                "transports" : ['websocket', 'polling']                //forces the transport to be only websocket. Server needs to be setup as well/
        }

        socket = io('http://10.3.3.141:3000', connectionOptions);
        socket.on('open', function(){ console.log("Client Open a connection.");});

        socket.on('connect', function(){ 
            console.log("Client Connected.");

            socket.on("my-channel", function(msg){ 
                if(msg == null){
                    console.log("MSG is Null");
                    return;
                }

                var activityItem = '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-cell">'+msg.dd.ipaddress+'</div></div>';
                $("#activity-threat-body").prepend(activityItem);
                $("#activity-threat-body>.table-row:nth-child(6)").remove();
            });

        });
        socket.on('connect_timeout', function(){ console.log("Client Connection timeout.");});
        socket.on('connect_error', function(){ 
            console.log("Client connection error.");
            socket.connect();
        });
        socket.on('reconnect_attempt', function(){ console.log("Client reconnect attempt.");});
        socket.on('reconnect', function(){console.log("Client Reconnected.");});
        socket.on('reconnect_error', function(){ console.log("Client Reconnect Error.");});
        socket.on('reconnect_failed', function(){ console.log("Client Reconnect Failed.");});
        socket.on('close', function(){ console.log("Client connection closed.");});
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
           console.log("Client Disconnected");
           socket.connect();
        });

    });
```

Comment: How come you still refresh the page after terminating node?

Comment: i want to refresh client html 5 page not the node. I am not going to stop Nodejs Server.

Comment: Code please. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my question with server side and client side. I want to connect when it disconnect automatically.